# "TypeError: (this.internalValue || []).slice is not a function" while using autocomplete multiple

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify component autocomplete multiple but when I try to select multiple values  "TypeError: (this.internalValue || []).slice is not a function " error occurs. Other autocomplete are working fine but when I select multiple value from this particular dropdown then it is giving me issue.

HTML templete -

```
<v-autocomplete key="id" :items="academicYears" v-model="academicYearID"
    item-text="academicYear" item-value="id" multiple
    chips small-chips required>
</v-autocomplete>
```

```
data () {
  return {
    modules: {
    academicYears: [],
    academicYearID: '', //Here I tried with academicYearID: [] still same error is coming up.
}
}}
```

```
getAcademicYears: async function () {
  try {
      const { data } = await http.get(`${constants.API_URL}/api/getAllYears`)
      this.academicYears = data.rows
      console.log('this.academicYears:', this.academicYears) //Also attached SS of this console.
    } catch (e) {
      const errorMessage = (e && e.response && e.response.data.message) || e.message
      this.errMsg(errorMessage)
  }
}
```

[image]

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Shouldn't `data()` return an array? I don't know much about Vue so please disregard my comment if not applicable.

Comment: You have `multiple` but a value is a string

Comment: @EstusFlask I changed v-model value to empty array but still same error is coming up

Comment: You get this error because whatever this.internalValue is, doesn't have a slice method.

Comment: @alessandromanzini But there is nothing called as this.internalValue in my entire code

Comment: @Jazz It's probably an internal key to some value you're binding. If that's not the case, there might be a bug with the component you're using

Comment: @alessandromanzini There was issue with binding.